# Plotting just color dots in R to represent 0's and 1's

Tags: r, plot

I am interested in plotting a row of 1's and 0's as a single row of green and red dots. I am new to R and have not found a plotting solution to do this. Example: `numbers = c(1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0)`.  Plot that as a single row of `(green dot, red dot, red dot, green dot, green dot,...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(x = seq_along(numbers),
     y = rep(1, length(numbers)),
     pch = 19,
     col = c("red","green")[1 + (numbers == 1)],
     ann = FALSE,
     axes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.